# Create a query to select all devices ordered from most expensive ones to cheapest

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench

hi i need to getall devices ordered from most expensive ones to cheapest.
i try this query

```
SELECT Price
* FROM Printer,Laptop,Pc
ORDER By Price ASC;
```

but i got this output

```
missing expression
```

so my tables are this

```
              *PC*
SERIAL_NUMBER   MODEL   PRICE   SPEED   RAM HD  CD
              *LAPTOP*
SERIAL_NUMBER   MODEL   PRICE   SPEED   RAM HD  SCREEN
                *PRINTER*
MODEL   PRICE
               *PRODUCT*
MODEL   MAKER   TYPE
s-1  Hitachi     laptop
```

Comment: funny almost tthe same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638066/i-need-a-query-to-select-most-expensive-product-for-every-maker/64638125#64638125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to perform a query on three separate tables which are not linked with any one-to-many relationship, but they have a few common fields.

So please use UNION to do the query and order the result by price

```
select model, price from printer 
union
select model, price from laptop
union
select model, price from pc
order by price desc
```

Note: to display the result from most expensive to cheapest, the price order should be "DESC" (in descending order)